# "Have you spoken English recently" vs. "Have you spoken in English recently"

Tags: prepositions, present-perfect

Do you **speak a language** or **speak *in* a language** when asking if someone has been practising it?

For example, which of these is better:

> **A:** Have you spoken English recently?
>   **B:** Have you spoken **in** English recently?

Comment: I would ask, "Have you practiced speaking English recently?" That puts the emphasis on speaking. I might also ask, "Have you practiced speaking in English recently?" That puts the emphasis on *English* as opposed to another language. Either is correct but one has a different emphasis from the other.

Comment: The obvious one here is: Have you spoken English recently. versus: He spoke in English to the class, for example. Your "in" one just would not be used.

Answer (score 1):

*To speak a language* can refer to specific acts of speaking,  **or** to one's ability, or customary behaviour.

*To speak in a language* is used only for specific acts of speaking.

Answer (score 0):

> **Have you spoken English recently**?
>
> **Have you spoken in English recently**?

There is not much difference syntacticaly but the use of the preposition **in** makes some difference in meaning.
  I think in a monolingual country like  England, you can not ask **Have you spoken in English**?

In a Multilingual country one may ask  **Have you spoken in English  recently**?

When there is no choice, we speak a language.When there is choice we may speak in a language.

Everybody expected that The Indian Prime Minister would speak at the UNO conference In English but he spoke in Hindi.

I think there is a slight difference between the two.

*We speak **a** language*, means speaks naturally probably as our mother tongue or with native like fluency.

If *we speak **in** a language*, we may not have that naturalness or native like fluency.

*He spoke English very authoritatively* ✓

but not

*He spoke in English very authoritatively*. ✗

> I tried speaking **in** English but I found it difficult.

A nonnative speaker starts speaking **in** English and starts speaking it after he/she has mastered it.

Here are two links which make the difference clear

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218506/speak-english-vs-speak-in-english

https://www.englishforums.com/English/SpeakEnglishSpeakEnglish/zdxxw/post.htm
.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A.It is a  long time since you cursed me.I am joking.Thank you  for the edit.What  about  its correctness.

Comment: Not my downvote, actually I'm surprised that you received one. The only (small) defect I can find is the  expression "not/felicity of expression" which you use to describe the meaning of "speaking a language". I'm not sure what you mean by them. The rest is perfectly good, but needed emphasis and some formatting.

Comment: But, and this is why I didn't upvote it, there's no mention of the OP's example "Have you spoken English recently?" I get the "He spoke English authoritatively" mirrors the OP's example, but the tense is different and the OP is asking about practising one's English, so your example is good but  a little removed from the OP's request.

Comment: One last thing, I didn't curse you. I never curse anyone, to curse someone means to wish ill of them, to desire their suffering and pain. I have never said anything of the kind.

Comment: @Mari-LouA.I was just joking.I know you are not that kind  of  woman.I have great  respect  for you.You have kept your word by placing  a bounty on my question. You have been guiding me  a lot since I became a member on this  site